# SQLite copy a sample of the database

Tags: sqlite

I have a fairly complex sqlite database with several tables and indices.  I'd like to copy a small subset of all the rows into a new database that I can use to test an app.  Is there any builtin export functionality that can do something like that?  eg.  `.clone db where titles.id < 100`;

Thanks.

Comment: typically you would just write the scripts to do this.

Comment: thanks, ya just wondering if there's a sqlite cli command for this.

Comment: I think a combination of .export and head would work well